# When I am trying run my C# created API it is throwing an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, error-handling

> Error CS1061
> 'HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'MapHttpAttributeRout' and no accessible extension method 'MapHttpAttributeRout' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> CumulativeProjectJigarmehta   C:\JJ\CumulativeProjectJigarmehta\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs 15  Active

I do not understand what went wrong when I created my project...

I tried creating my project twice, it is throwing the same error both times.

Comment: Well, read the error message. It says you are trying to call a method named _MapHttpAttributeRout_ on an instance of type _HttpConfiguration_, but _HttpConfiguration_ has no method of such name (nor is there a _HttpConfiguration_ extension method of that name), hence why trying to do so is futile and not possible. TL;DR: Trying to call _MapHttpAttributeRout_ on _HttpConfiguration_ is a no can do.

Comment: That's a **compilation error** not a runtime exception.  `MapHttpAttributeRout` looks like a misspelling.  Did you actually want **[`MapHttpAttributeRoutes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn201974(v=vs.118))** from [`HttpConfigurationExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj125362(v=vs.118))?

Comment: Hello, is it possible to take a look at the answer I provided?

Answer (score 0):

[**CS1061**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061) is a compilation error, not an exception that gets thrown in runtime:

> This error occurs when you try to call a method or access a class member that does not exist.

`MapHttpAttributeRout` looks to be a misspelling.  You probably meant to call the extension method **[`MapHttpAttributeRoutes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn201974(v=vs.118))** from [`HttpConfigurationExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj125362(v=vs.118)).

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by a class name that duplicates the form name. You can change the class name that is different from the form name. If it doesn't work, please share more information.